# Как в моем примере проверить key в localStorage при загрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript

Как получить и проверить `key` при загрузке страницы я могу, но не в этом примере:

По нажатию на имя в списке я заношу так, как он написан в хранилище (если Alica, то записывается Alica, если Cristopher, то соответственно Cristopher), где ему добавляется `true|false`. Это значит, что по нажатию добавляется класс. При загрузке страницы я пытаюсь проверить тот самый `key`, который был записан, и если `true` навесить класс, если `false` - ничего. У меня возникает проблема получить `key`. В интернете я не могу найти близкие примеры, а те что есть уже подтянул.

Помогите пожалуйста.

```
//Listen click

var index = 0;  

    contact = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.rd-guides li'));

        contact.forEach(function(e, i){
            e.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                index = i;
                    add();
            });
        });

    //Add name and class in lS

        guide = document.querySelectorAll('.guide');

            function add(){
                check = contact[index].classList.toggle('no-work');
                    localStorage.setItem(guide[index].innerHTML, check);
            };
```

Я могу без проблем занести в `localStorage`, что-то вроде такого ключа: `localStorage.getItem('mykey-' + index, check`) и на выходе получить, что-то очень не красивое типа `mykey-0, mykey-1` и т.д. Я же пытаюсь научиться делать все по красоте. Любая помощь карается плюсиками от меня

Comment: Все слова вроде понятны, а вот смысла я уловить не могу

Comment: Я кликаю на <p class="class">Hello word</p>, выполняется функция: добавляется класс и заносится в localStorage запись, вот такая - Hello word true. На любой элемент с таким классом выполняется одна и та же функция. Проблема в том, что не могу написать условие при загрузки страницы, которое проверит key и если true накинет класс. Так понятней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на so не работает local storage, работает вот [тут](https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/wOGjza)

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.example');
[].slice.call(nodes).forEach(handle);

function handle(node) {
  let txt = node.innerText;
  node.addEventListener('click', () => {
    node.classList.add('clicked');
    localStorage.setItem(txt, true);
  });
  if (localStorage.getItem(txt))
    node.classList.add('clicked');
}
```

```css
.example {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="example">hello world 1</p>
<p class="example">hello world 2</p>
<p class="example">hello world 3</p>
```

Comment: А где у Вас проверка при загрузке страницы? Точнее посему при перезагрузке все осталось как было(в смысле работает)?

Comment: @Ученик if (localStorage.getItem(txt))
    node.classList.add('clicked');

Comment: А почему тогда у меня не проверяет?(я не включил фрагмент кода, но также писал if(guide in localStorage) и if(localStorage.getItem(guide)) )

Comment: @Ученик ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯